# How Do I Write DateTimeOffset to SQL Server Using Sequelize and Node.Js

Tags: sql-server, node.js, azure-sql-database, sequelize.js

I have a date and time value (UTC time) and I need to write it to a DateTimeOffset type column on SQL Server on Azure using the Sequelize ORM with Node.Js. How do I go about in doing so?